# Bash alias of an svn command piped to awk

Tags: svn, bash, awk

I type in this command frequently, and was trying to alias it, and couldn't for some reason.

```
for FILE in `svn stat | awk '{print $2}'`; do svn revert $FILE; done
```

This obviously does a large number of svn reverts.

when I alias it:

```
alias revert_all="for FILE in `svn stat | awk '{print $2}'`; do svn revert $FILE; done"
```

svn stat runs immediately - no good

Then I try double-quoting the awk portion:

```
alias revert_all='for FILE in `svn stat | awk "{print $2}"`; do svn revert $FILE; done'
```

but this does not run properly - the awk portion does not execute (I get the M values showing up and try to run svn revert M).

next try, with escaped single tick quotes:

```
alias revert_all='for FILE in `svn stat | awk \'{print $2}\'`; do svn revert $FILE; done'
```

The command does not complete, bash is waiting for another tick?

I know I could script this, or put the awk command in the file, but I'm not looking for a workaround.  There is something here I don't know.  What is it?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backticks make getting the quoting right very difficult.

Try this:

```
alias revert_all='for FILE in $(svn stat | awk '{print $2}'); do svn revert "$FILE"; done'
```

Using `$()` allows quotes inside it to be independent of quotes outside it.

It's best to always use `$()` and [never use backticks](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082).

Comment: The problem with $() is that it's not portable and bash, though very popular, is not installed everywhere.

Comment: Hmmm... POSIX specifies `$()`: http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_03 - besides the question is tagged "[bash]"

Answer (score 3):

I note you are not interesting in workarounds, but it seems as much usefull the native way. Do not alias, but define as function and put .bashrc:

```
revert_all() { for FILE in `svn stat | awk '{print $2}'`; do svn revert $FILE; done}
```

Just tested:

```
alias revert_all="for FILE in \`svn stat | awk '{print $2}'\`; do svn revert $FILE; done"
```

works.

Answer (score 2):

Can’t you just do `svn revert --recursive`?

Answer (score 2):

why do you want to use alias? define it as a function and put it inside a file. This will act as a "library". When you want to use the function, source it in your scripts.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to avoid the backticks completely with:

```
svn stat | awk '{print $2}' | while read FILE; do svn revert $FILE; done
```

The next is to use eval.

Comment: one of several reasons: failure to use xargs (lots of people love xargs), vague response w.r.t. eval, or most likely because the proper solution is to use a function instead of an alias.