# bash shell: how to write the alias correctly

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm trying to write down some alias in Bash involving xclip.
The idea is that I want to copy the output of 'pwd' into the clipboard buffer,
and after a bunch of directory changes, I want to go back to where I typed 'pwd'.

I wrote down something in my .bashrc file:

```
alias putclip='xclip'
alias getclip='xclip -o'
alias wd="pwd | putclip"
alias dw="cd `getclip`"
```

So in the terminal, 'wd' mean I copy the current directory into clipboard, and 'dw' supposed to get me back to that dir afterward.

However, this didn't work in my terminal.

The following code always worked:

```
$ pwd | xclip
$ cd ***
$ cd ***
$ cd `xclip -o`
```

Any ideas how to fix this?
Thanks!

UPDATE:

- by "didn't work" I meant there was no error message, but 'dw' simply
  sent me to the home dir.
- I'm aware of pushd/popd, but it doesn't
  serve for my purposes. It is important for me to get things
  transferred via clipboard s.t. other software/applications can get
  involved.
- the double quotes were typos, just fixed them.

UPDATE 2:
   using single quote for wd/dw fixed the problem!

Comment: What is "didn't work"?  Was there an error message or did nothing happen?  Did you remember to do `source ~/.bashrc`?

Comment: I use single quotes for aliases. May be that is the cause, just a guess.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1833801/bash-alias-of-an-svn-command-piped-to-awk

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to declare the aliases with single quotes, otherwise the `xclip` command will be executed when you declare the alias.

Comment: Just fixed the quotes, please have a look again? I don't understand how to translate cd `xclip -o` into correct Bash script...

Comment: @galactica You haven't fixed all the double quotes! There are still some double quotes.

Answer (score 3):

There is a much better way using `pushd`, `dirs` and `popd`:

- If you want to remember your current directory so that you can easily return later, instead of changing directory with `cd`, use `pushd`.
- The `pushd` bash builtin changes directory like `cd`, but it pushes the current directory to a "directory stack".
- The `dirs` bash builtin shows the directories you have pushed on the directory stack.
- The `popd` bash builtin changes directory back to the one most recently pushed on the stack, and it removes it from the stack.

It works like this:

```
$ pwd
/i/am/here
$ pushd /tmp
$ cd /some/where       # do some work
$ cd /etc/other/place  # do some work
$ popd     # back to where I did pushd last time
$ pwd
/i/am/here
```